# How to set the master's name of a chatbot using PyAIML?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, chatbot, aiml

I was playing with PyAIML. I understand how to set the bot's name. But could not figure out how to set the creator's name so that if anyone ask's "Who created you?" then it can reply appropriately. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

It's the same way you set and get the botname. Only the variable name differs to your choice.